# Powershell Function -WhatIf for cmdlet without the -WhatIf support?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-powershell

For these cmdlets below, I try to create the function with the `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` line, but not sure that it will work.

Using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0

How can the script be modified to support the `-WhatIf` parameter?

```
function Remove-License {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param ([String] $UserPrincipalName )
    
    $AssignedLicense = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses.AccountSkuId

    $AssignedLicense |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing $($UserPrincipalName) License $($AssignedLicense)..." -ForegroundColor Red
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -RemoveLicenses $_ -Verbose
    }

}

Remove-License -UserPrincipalName 'User.Name@domain.com' -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [guiwhatsthat helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72684652/15339544), if you want **your function** to support [Common Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2) including `-WhatIf` as well as `-Confirm`, [`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2#pscmdletshouldprocess) is how you do it.

If instead you want [**`Set-MsolUserLicense`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0) to support it, you would need to create a [**proxy command**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) / proxy function around this cmdlet to extend it's functionality.

These blogs demonstrate how to do it:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/

---

To address some issues on your code, you should note that `-RemoveLicenses` takes `string[]` as input, this means you can pass the whole array of *licenses to remove* as argument.

You could use [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-7.2) instead of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2) to display information about what the function is doing (since your function already supports `-Verbose`, this would be logical). Also, `-Verbose` is being used always activated on `Set-MsolUserLicense` which can be confusing if someone else using your function does not want to see verbose messages (this is addressed on the example below).

You can also use [`ConfirmImpact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2#confirmimpact) set to **High**, this way the function will always ask for confirmation before processing any license removal assuming `-WhatIf` was not being used. **`-Confirm:$false` becomes the alternative to avoid such confirmation messages.**

```bash
function Remove-License {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string] $UserPrincipalName
    )

    process {
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess([string] $UserPrincipalName, 'Remove License')) {
            $licenses = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses.AccountSkuId
            $param    = @{
                UserPrincipalName = $UserPrincipalName
                RemoveLicenses    = $licenses
                Verbose           = $PSBoundParameters['Verbose'] 
            }
            Set-MsolUserLicense @param
        }
    }
}
```

Now the function supports [*pipeline processing*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process), you can process multiple users by piping it into other cmdlets, i.e.:

```bash
Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter DisabledOnly -MaxResults 5 | Remove-License -WhatIf
```

Comment: Wow, thank you @Santiago, this is so cool, I appreciate it very muchly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess

```
if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("Some text to display")){ 
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -RemoveLicenses $_ -Verbose
 }
```

MS Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Hi @guiwhatsthat, thank you for the reply, so even though there is no -WhatIf parameter in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0, I assume it is still possible ?

Comment: sorry I did not look into the command, it will not work so there is only one option. will update my answer

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer if you're asking if the WhatIf message will be displayed the answer is yes. If you want `Set-MsolUserLicense` to be the one having the `-WhatIf` switch then you need a proxy command wrapper around this cmdlet